# Where is the workdir folders in Docker?

Tags: docker

Im new to Docker and currently reading the docs as I go along. I also cant get my head around changing files in docker.

I've created a docker file on my local iMac:

**Dockerfile:**

```
from ubuntu:14.04

# Install prerequisites
run apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    curl \
    git \
    libcurl3-dev \
    libleptonica-dev \
    liblog4cplus-dev \
    libopencv-dev \
    libtesseract-dev \
    wget

# Copy all data
copy . /srv/openalpr


# Setup the build directory
run mkdir /srv/openalpr/src/build
workdir /srv/openalpr/src/build

# Setup the compile environment
run cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR:PATH=/etc .. && \
    make -j2 && \
    make install

workdir /data

entrypoint ["alpr"]
```

That file is inside a folder called "foo": `foo/Dockerfile` Inside `foo` folder, I'm expected to see this folder path: `/srv/openalpr/src/build` but I see nothing. What is and where is that folder? I thought ubuntu would be installed there? Basically I need to `nano` some files in x location inside ubuntu. Where and how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be under the impression that Docker creates an Ubuntu installation inside the folder `foo`. That's not quite right. The Docker environment is inside a "container" - think of it much like a virtual machine (while technically incorrect, it's a good way to think about it for now).

You should build your Dockerfile:

```
cd foo
docker build -t "Sylar/mydocker:latest" .
```

Then, to see the folder `/srv/openalpr/...`, you should get to a bash prompt *inside* the container. From there, you can `cd` and `ls` to look around:

```
docker run --rm -it Sylar/mydocker:latest /bin/bash
```

Comment: Fascinating. I have not seen that example in the docker docs as yet. I'll give this a go tomorrow and report back. Thanks.

Comment: On a mac, the containers are also running in a virtual machine, so they are another step away from the user

Comment: @Matt Sorry to be late. Tried that but it keeps downloading something.

Comment: Downloading is normal. Your Dockerfile says `FROM ubuntu:14.04` and it needs to download that image as a starting point.